# Synchronized oscillations

Tags: terminology, oscillators

Please I'm a little confused about this. When are oscillations said to be synchronized? Is it because they **vibrate at the same frequency** or because **they are in phase**? Got a question with both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oscillations are synchronised iff they are in phase. But the term is sometimes used a bit loosely, so I would always recommend to say 'of the same frequency' or 'in phase'.

Comment: And usually if they stay in phase for some time.  So same frequency also. But yes, sometimes people mean just freq. in synchronizing receiver clocks to transmitter clocks one tries to sync both. If only freq  it is you can't do phase coherent detection, but you might be able to do differential phase detection (ber is higher)

Comment: It's definitely a term with a loose definition.  I've also seen it used to refer to oscillators who are at the same frequency whose phase is different, but the difference is known.  For example, you could have two oscillators that are synchronized "180 degrees out of phase."